# VBA - Pivot table refresh 1004 application not defined error

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I am getting an object defined error 1004 when i try to run a macro to update the pviot. I want the pivot and chart to update daily so it always shows the last 30 days

```
'pivot filter refresh

Dim DateToday As Date
DateToday = Date
Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("Pivot1")

PvtTbl.PivotFields("DateAdded").PivotFilters. _
    Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=DateToday - 30, Value2:=DateToday
```

Comment: what happens if you do this manually and record the macro. is the syntax on that last line any different (besides differences in variables)?

Comment: I did record it manually. All i changed was Value1 and Value2 of the pivot filters. Originally I had the default Activesheet.Pivottable... syntax and i was getting the error.  So I defined the objects and I thought that would fix it, but it has not

Comment: This all looks correct. Upon which line do you get the error?

Comment: Last 2 lines  ----- PvtTbl.PivotFields("DateAdded").PivotFilters. _
    Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=DateToday - 30, Value2:=DateToday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem with one of my own pivot tables. The solution is to `ClearAllFilters` ***from that particular pivot field*** before attempting to apply your new filter.

One additional check that may be necessary (and not shown here) is to check to make sure the field you're filtering is actually visible before filtering.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim dateToday As Date
    dateToday = Date
    Dim pvtTbl As PivotTable
    Set pvtTbl = Staffing.PivotTables(1)

    Dim ptField As PivotField
    Set ptField = pvtTbl.PivotFields("FiscalMonth")

    ptField.ClearAllFilters
    ptField.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, _
                              Value1:=dateToday - 30, _
                              Value2:=dateToday

End Sub
```